# Internet Browsers acting weird

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard

Having weird issues attempting to type on multiple browsers.  In a generic way it seems as if one of the CTRL keys are stuck, but not always.  In Firefox, I am unable to type anything at all anywhere.

Chrome, my usual browsing program - when typing in the address bar - "a" highlights everything that was previously typed; "c" works if something else is already typed; "v"-pastes (like ctrl-v); "z" -undo (like ctrl-z). Numbers, special characters, and all other letters work just fine.  Holding shift, "A-U" work correctly, "V" still pastes, "W-Z" work correctly.  With Cap Lock on, I have the same issues with "V" and "Z".  Finally backspace deletes entire "words" (http:www.google.com - one press deletes com, second press deletes google., third press deletes www., forth press deletes http; arrow keys also act the same way - left jumps one "word" at a time.  In the google search bar the same issues seem present, however backspace will not work at all, nor will the arrow keys.

To throw insult to everything - absolutely no issues in Internet Explorer.  All other programs (File Explorer, Word, Excel, RDP, etc seem unaffected).

The issue is present when using the physical keyboard, as well as the on-screen keyboard.

Help??

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions:

1. Repeatedly press and release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, first the left
   one, the the right one.
2. Restart your computer.